# Why do Scalar-valued functions in the "where" clause get slower?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Unfortunately, I can’t prepare an example so that you can repeat it on your computer, but I think this is not necessary to understand what the problem is.
There is such query:

```
with cte as (
select  selectStations.ReceiverUID, 1907 as id
    from WF4_Routes r WITH (NOLOCK) 
    inner join WF4_Stages selectStages WITH (NOLOCK) on selectStages.RouteID = r.ID and r.SentToCAS = 1 and r.PRUZ <> 1 and selectStages.PRUZ <> 1 and selectStages.StageType = 1 
    inner join WF4_Stations selectStations WITH (NOLOCK) on selectStations.ApprovalStageID = selectStages.ID and selectStations.PRUZ <> 1
)
select *--case when dbo.fnGetGkExchangeParticipantQuick(cte.ReceiverUID, id)  = 'E477B8FA-7539-4B43-8961-807A29FECFC0' then 1 else 0 end
from cte
where dbo.fnGetGkExchangeParticipantQuick(cte.ReceiverUID, id) = 'E477B8FA-7539-4B43-8961-807A29FECFC0'
```

From the whole script, the moment of calling the scalar function in the "where" condition and the commented out call in "select" is important.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].fnGetGkExchangeParticipantQuick(@CurrentUID uniqueidentifier, @IsExchangeParticipantAttrID int) 
RETURNS uniqueidentifier 
AS  
BEGIN 
  declare @UnitUID uniqueidentifier 

  select @UnitUID = UID from GL_OBJECTS where UID = @CurrentUID and ACTIVE = 1

  while @UnitUID is not null
  begin
    if (select top 1 cast(PropertyValue as bit) from MB_ATTRIBUTES_TO_VALUES where Object_UID = @UnitUID and Attribute_ID = @IsExchangeParticipantAttrID) = 1 
        break;

    set @UnitUID = null
    select @UnitUID = PARENT from GL_OBJECTS where UID = @UnitUID and ACTIVE = 1
  end

  return @UnitUID
END
GO
```

The function searches for a specific attribute from the parent in the hierarchy of objects.

If I call this function in the "where" condition, then the query will execute in 1 second, while reading from the disk will be about 600 thousand records. If I call this function in the "select" condition, then the function will execute in 10 milliseconds, the number of reads from disk 30.

If you look at the plan, you can see that for some reason the scheduler fulfills the "with" condition with the "where" condition, i.e. he is trying to optimize the execution of combining the condition, I do not need it. I tried to add grouping to the "with" condition or the "distinct" condition does not help.

Please help me understand what the problem is?

Comment: I was helped by your comment with a proposal to move the function to the "with" block. This seems like a solution to my problem.

Comment: Note: you shouldn't be using `nolock` unless you absolutely have to as the results are unpredictable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CTE is often no more than syntactical sugar, SQL Server combines the whole query into a single execution plan that it thinks best.

You can sometimes work around this by adding the function call in the CTE as a column and then using it in your `where` clause.

```
with cte as (
    select selectStations.ReceiverUID
      , 1907 as id
      , dbo.fnGetGkExchangeParticipantQuick(selectStations.ReceiverUID, 1907) as ExchangeParticipant
    from WF4_Routes r WITH (NOLOCK) 
    inner join WF4_Stages selectStages WITH (NOLOCK) on selectStages.RouteID = r.ID and r.SentToCAS = 1 and r.PRUZ <> 1 and selectStages.PRUZ <> 1 and selectStages.StageType = 1 
    inner join WF4_Stations selectStations WITH (NOLOCK) on selectStations.ApprovalStageID = selectStages.ID and selectStations.PRUZ <> 1
)
select *
from cte
where ExchangeParticipant = 'E477B8FA-7539-4B43-8961-807A29FECFC0';
```

Notes:

You should never use a scalar function in a `where` clause as indexes can't be used and frequently a full table scan is required.

And if you need to force the CTE part of the query to execute first then you can materialise the results into a temp table and then select from that. This way SQL Server creates two independent execution plans.